# Swift save base64 audio file using Data says file does not exist

Tags: swift

I have downloaded a base64 byte array of an audio file using a web service.  I saved it but I cannot play as it errors with message:

```
failed to play audio The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error 1954115647.)
```

This is my method to save the file in FileUtil.swift class:

```
  class func saveAudioFile(messageId: Int, data: Data) -> String? {
        let filename = FileUtil.getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent(messageId.description)
        do {
            try data.write(to: filename)
            return filename.absoluteString
        }
        catch{
            print("failed to write video file with messageId: \(messageId)")
            return nil
        }
    }`
```

This is how I call the method:

```
 let data = Data(base64Encoded: (mybase64Value)!)!
 fileName = FileUtil.saveAudioFile(messageId: Int(message.messageId), data: data)!
```

I tried to check if the file exists and it says it doesn't.
Is there another API to save audio file?  Or what am I missing?  Any help appreciated.

Thank you

The audio is generated on a Android device and sent to a web service which stores the file. The IOS device downloads the audio file as base64 encoded byte array. Once the message is downloaded, I save it using that method. But not able to play it. 
I even check if the file exists using this api:

```
let fileManager = FileManager.default 
if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: filename.absoluteString)
```

and it says it does not. I would like to have a method to save the file using the Data but it seems like my method is not the right way as saving is not working.

The file name looks like: file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/404E6FFD-224B-43E5-80A8-DF1C9746BC7E/Documents/2199. The messageId is a Int64 type and description is just friendly way to print it out.

Comment: Can you show the code where you try to read the file? What is the value of `filename`?

Comment: `OSStatus` error `1954115647` is `kAudioFileStreamError_UnsupportedFileType`, which suggests your audio file data is in the incorrect format. Unfortunately that's about all I can tell you since the code you'd provided doesn't seem to be the same as the code that caused your error message (it seems to be in a "play" method rather than a "write" method).

Comment: How you know your audio file extension?. You have passing messageId.description, Is this contains any mp3 like or other audio file extension ?

Answer (score 0):

After sending over a mp3 audio format for the IOS swift code to download the problem is fixed.